# Unity make Joystick always result in speed 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

So I have a joystick object, which gives me values of -1 to 1 for each axis.

```
float horizontalMove = joystick.Horizontal * speed;
float verticalMove = joystick.Vertical * speed;

rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalMove, verticalMove, 0);
```

Now, what I want is that no matter how far you pull the joystick in each direction, it will always result in speed 1. Just like how my current code works, but my joystick is always pulled to the edge. I also made it so max. 1 directions can be set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.normalized`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-normalized.html) property of the vector, which ensures it either has length 1, or is equal to `Vector3.zero`.

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalMove, verticalMove, 0).normalized;
```

Unlike using `Mathf.Sign` on each axis, the angle of the vector is preserved, so the player will still be able to move in any orientation, not just along axes and diagonals.

Comment: Well this is not how I understood the question but apparently what OP was actually looking for ^^

Comment: @derHugo I can understand how you interpreted it that way! I was a bit confused too until I saw your answer and the comments.